# Exception when getting job execution status in Spring-XD Admin

Tags: spring, spring-batch, spring-xd

I am trying to see the execution status of a job I ran, but at some random points I get the following error:

```
2015-10-14T14:41:24-0400 1.2.0.RELEASE ERROR qtp195949131-28 rest.RestControllerAdvice - Caught exception while handling a request
org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotWritableException: Could not write content: java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to java.lang.String (through reference chain: org.springframework.xd.rest.domain.JobExecutionInfoResource["jobExecution"]->org.springframework.batch.core.JobExecution["executionContext"]->org.springframework.batch.item.ExecutionContext["values"]->java.util.concurrent.EntrySetView[0]->java.util.concurrent.MapEntry["value"]->java.util.ArrayList[0]); nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to java.lang.String (through reference chain: org.springframework.xd.rest.domain.JobExecutionInfoResource["jobExecution"]->org.springframework.batch.core.JobExecution["executionContext"]->org.springframework.batch.item.ExecutionContext["values"]->java.util.concurrent.EntrySetView[0]->java.util.concurrent.MapEntry["value"]->java.util.ArrayList[0])
```

Now, I say "random", but the truth is I don't even know which step causes this exception since those are the only logs I have. The jobs run successfully with seemingly no errors, but this really worries me. I've been looking online for days for this, but I don't see anything that can either help me debug this, or even gives an inkling of what might cause this. Any help?

Thanks, N.S.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so I figured out that the problem was that we were serializing in the execution context a List>, and one of those internal maps contained an Integer as an Object instead of a String. This seems to cause the deserialization of the context to crash.

Solution? Don't store that list within the execution context (instead we wrote the whole list object to a file for transferring between various steps).